# Is this awkward dryer exhaust plan manageable?

Tags: dryer, ventilation

I'd like to replace my 90's era washer/dryer with a modern one, but my space constraints are very strict. I can't get a dryer that sticks out any further from the wall than my current one, which is 25.5" deep and vents out the back.

GE dryers let me vent out the left side, from what I've read, and this should gain me a few inches of precious clearance and let me get a 27"D model.

**However** the exhaust hookup is only a few inches away from the dryer on the floor, and I'm having trouble visualizing how this would connect using standard components. Can I just run a flexible duct from the side of the dryer, do an immediate 90 degree turn and plug it into the floor a few inches away? It might even need to loop up and back down.

This is the current setup:
[image: Current setup image]

I'm planning on having a handyman do the installation but I want to make sure its reasonable before I place the order.

Comment: If you're unable to get this to work, take a look at stackable washer/dryer combo units, all-in-one units, and heat pump dryers. All of these will have a cost premium, but are good for space saving.

Comment: i don't see a big diff between going from behind to the floor versus the side to the floor...

Comment: That rigid 90 degree turn you currently have may be able to be trimmed with tin snips to fit on the side of your new dryer directly.

Comment: Many dryers have the ability to change the vent location  from the back panel to the side panel. There is a knockout on the side and you run the vent out of that hole allowing you to get the dryer 4 inches closer to the wall.

Comment: @AlaskaMan - Yes that is why I have zeroed in on GE dryers - I'm just having a little trouble visualizing the vent going from the side knockout to the floor exit literally 3" away from the dryer.

Comment: Nelluk look down the back of your dryer, the left side will be the same except that 90 will be rotated to the front instead of parallel with the back.